# redirect after form submit gives a 404 error using WWW::Mechanize (perl)

Tags: perl, parsing, www-mechanize

I'm trying to fetch the date of the next episode of a specific tv show in [this site](http://next-episode.net/) using Mechanize in perl.

```
# getting episode number & date

# create a new browser
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);

# fill search form, getting to tv show page
my $url= "http://next-episode.net/";
$browser->get($url);
$browser->form_name("search");
$browser->field("search", "big bang");
$browser->click();

print $browser->content();
```

I can't get to the tv show web-page. I only get the 404 page: "Sorry, the page you're looking for cannot be found! You may have typed a wrong url, or it may've been linked badly or moved."

am I filling the form wrongly?

Comment: ofc "big bang" will be a variable eventually. atm I'm using "big bang" just for a reference since searching that manually gets me to the right page.

Comment: Looking at the page it looks like that form usually runs a javascript rather than submitting a form. (Mechanize doesn't do JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ? :

```
my $url = "http://next-episode.net";
my $search = "big bang";

use WWW::Mechanize;
use URI::Escape;
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

my $string = uri_escape $search;
$browser->get("$url/site-search-$string.html");

print $browser->content();
```

And if you'd like to know the number of days remaining to wait, add the extra line :

```
print "$1 days to wait\n" if $browser->content() =~ /(\d+)\s+Day\(s\)\s+/;
```

(I use regex here because `HTML` here is odd)

Comment: That's great! it's a lot better (and shorter) than what I wrote :-)

Comment: No need cookies, removed. Thanks to upvote/accept the answer if it fit your needs